# How to add left outer join to grouped and summed LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have an Employees table:

```
EmployeeID  |  EmployeeName
---------------------------
1           |  Jack
2           |  Jill
3           |  Roger
```

And an Occurrences table:

```
OccurrenceID  |  EmployeeID  |  Points
--------------------------------------
1             |  1           |  5
2             |  2           |  3
3             |  1           |  1
```

I have a working LINQ query that groups and sums the two table together:

```
groupedOccurrences = (from o in db.Occurrences.Include(o => o.Employee)
                      where o.OccurrenceDate >= beginDate
                         && o.OccurrenceDate <= endDate
                      group o by o.Employee.EmployeeName into g
                      select new OccurrenceByQuarter
                      {
                          Name = g.Key,
                          Total = g.Sum(o => o.Points)
                       });
```

Which produces this output:

```
 Jack 6
 Jill 3
```

But I want to also have employee Roger show up in the output with 0 points.  I've tried adding a join to the LINQ query like this:

```
groupedOccurrences = (from e in db.Employees
                      from o in db.Occurrences
                      join o in db.Occurrences on e.EmployeeID equals o.EmployeeID into j1
                      from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      group j2 by e.EmployeeName into g
                      select new OccurrenceByQuarter
                      {
                          Name = g.Key,
                          Total = g.Sum(o => o.Points)
                      });
```

But I end up with the number of points being vastly inflated (as in 24 times what they're supposed to be).

I've also tried to get the Total to return 0 if null by changing the declaration of Total to `public int? Total { get; set; }` in my OccurrencesByQuarter class but then when I try to change the LINQ query to include `Total = g.Sum(o => o.Points) ?? 0` I get an error that says "operator ?? cannot be applied to operands of type int and int".

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use group join:

```
groupedOccurrences = (from e in db.Employees
                      join o in db.Occurrences.Where(x => 
                                  x.OccurrenceDate >= beginDate &&
                                  x.OccurrenceDate <= endDate)
                           on e.EmployeeID equals o.EmployeeID into g
                      select new OccurrenceByQuarter
                      {
                          Name = e.EmployeeName,
                          Total = g.Sum(x => (int?)x.Points) ?? 0
                      });
```

Result will be:

```
Jack  6
Jill  3
Roger 0
```

In order to return `0` for empty groups cast summarized property to nullable, and then apply null-coalescing operator to return default value: `g.Sum(x => (int?)x.Points) ?? 0`

Comment: Awesome! The "into g" makes the linq statement effectively an outer join where if the into clause is omitted it merely performs a normal join and only matching rows will be retrieved. and there will be employee x Occurences of them versus the nice groups produced here